# How to use "map" function in Python? (How to rewrite a for loop?)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an array of classes and I want to create objects of them. This works:

```
    classArray = [Auto, Wheel]
    objectArray = []
    for myClass in classArray:
        objectArray += [myClass()]
```

Can I use the map function to accomplish the same?

```
    objectArray = map( ??? , classArray)
```

My apologies if this is a dumb question. I am fairly new to Python.

Comment: Use comprehensions. Forget about map 99% of the time

Comment: I don't find this to be a dumb question, but actually quite interesting!

Comment: I made your question more general. There is no fundamental difference between a function of `class -> instance` and `x -> y`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead. Many consider them to be preferred over the `map` function.

```
objectArrray = [ c() for c in classArray ]
```

---

If you insist on using `map`, you can do

```
map(lambda c: c(), classArray)
```

Here, I am creating an anonymous function with [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-forms) that simply takes the item, and calls it. If you are unfamiliar with [`map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), it takes a 1-parameter function as the first argument.

Comment: Also, since `map` just needs something callable, it doesn't need to be a `lambda`. For instance: `def classToInstance (c): return c(); map(classToInstance, classArray)`. Also, an "indentity" function could be used, as constructors are callable. In this case, `map` assumes such an "identity" function when `None` is passed: `map(None, classArray)` ... but that is just getting confusing!

Comment: Technically, you can do this without defining your own function, like so: `map(type.__call__, classArray)`. Explaining why this works would require delving further into the guts of the language than would be appropriate for a new Python user, but I thought I'd mention it anyway.